# How to call controller's update function

Tags: php, laravel, controller

I am trying to use controller's update function on my **dashboard.blade.php** page, but when I press on "Save" it switches to **show.blade.php** page instead of updating.

My **dashboard.blade.php** page:

```html
                    @if(count($posts) > 0 )
                            <table class="table table-striped">
                                <tr>
                                    <th>Title</th>
                                    <th>Body</th>
                                    <th>Employee Number</th>
                                    <th>Edit</th>
                                    <th>Save</th>
                                </tr>
                                @foreach($posts as $post)
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>{{$post->title}}</td>
                                        <td><input type='text' name='body'class='form-control' value='{{$post->body}}'></td>
                                        <td>{{$post->employee_no}}</td>
                                        <td><a href="{{ action("PostsController@update", $post->id) }}" >Save</a></td>
                                        <td><a href="/lsapp/public/posts/{{$post->id}}/edit" class="btn btn-default">Edit</a></td>
                                    </tr>
                                @endforeach
                            </table>
                    @else 
                        <p>You Have No Posts</p>
                    @endif
```

My update function on **PostsController.php** page:

```html
public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
        $this->validate($request,[
            //'title' => 'required',
            'body' => 'required'
            ]);
    
            //Update Post
            $post = Post::find($id);
            //$post->title = $request->input('title');
            $post->body = $request->input('body');
            $post->save();
    
           return redirect('/posts')->with('success','Post Updated');
    }
```

I read that "action" will go to the first route that matches the pattern, but I do not know how to solve this problem.

My **web.php** page:

```html
Route::get('/', 'PagesController@index');
Route::get('/about', 'PagesController@about');
Route::get('/services', 'PagesController@services');

Route::resource('posts','PostsController');


Auth::routes();

Route::get('/dashboard', 'DashboardController@index');
```

How can I call the update function correctly from **dashboard.blade.php** page?

Comment: Look up how to make an HTML form, then instead of using an anchor use a submit button and set the form to PUT/PATCH method,

You get the show page because the anchor goes to the GET posts/{post_id} version, you want the PUT/PATCH version of posts/{post_id} [more information on REST](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/controllers#resource-controllers)

Comment: Thanks a lot! but actually I would like to have a save button for every row in the table, it is possible with a submit button? There is no other way to call update function instead of using a form?

Comment: An other way would be to send an ajax request to posts/{post_id} with a put/patch method [See ajax requests via axios](https://github.com/axios/axios)

Answer (score 0):

To update data you have to use `form` with `put` method.
and route will be like this,

```
Route::put('dashboard/update/{id}',[
            'uses' => 'DashboardController@update',
            'as' => 'dashboard.update'
        ]);
```

For more [Laravel Routing](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/routing)

Hope it helps :)

Comment: OP already has a resource controller defined (resource controller already defines the update route)

Comment: okk, then but you have to specify `put` method in your `action`

Comment: Thanks a lot! I am actually looking for a solution without using form because I want a save button for each row in the table. Is there another way to call the update function on PostsController.php?

Comment: You can do one thing that you can show `save` button on every row and on click you can call method which returns view and after that you can update that.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this by using form submit with hidden PUT method.

```
<form action="{{ url('customers') }}/{{$data['customer']->id}}" method="POST">
        <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="PUT">
        @csrf
</form>
```

Comment: thanks a lot! I am actually looking for a solution without using form because I want a save button for each row in the table. Is there another way to call the update function on PostsController.php?

Answer (score 0):

How about having a simple form for each row in the table :

```
@if(count($posts) > 0 )
    <table class="table table-striped">
        <tr>
            <th>Title</th>
            <th>Body</th>
            <th>Employee Number</th>
            <th>Edit</th>
            <th>Save</th>
        </tr>
        @foreach($posts as $post)
            <tr>
                <td>{{$post->title}}</td>
                <td>{{$post->employee_no}}</td>
                <td>
                    <!-- Form for each row -->
                    <form action="{{ route("posts.update", [ 'post' => $post->id ]) }}" method="POST">
                        @method('PUT')
                        @csrf
                        <input type='text' name='body'class='form-control' value='{{$post->body}}'></td>
                        <button type="submit">Save</button>
                    </form>
                    <!-- Form for each row -->
                <td><a href="/lsapp/public/posts/{{$post->id}}/edit" class="btn btn-default">Edit</a></td>
            </tr>
        @endforeach
    </table>
@else 
    <p>You Have No Posts</p>
@endif
```

Comment: Thank you very much! but when I press the save button it does nothing.. maybe something is missing?